# ruby での Proc の Hash に相当することを swift で書きたい。

Tags: ruby, swift

ruby での次のようなコードと同等のことを swift でおこなうにはどのように記述すればよいでしょうか？

```
my_func_add = proc do |a, b|
  a + b
end

my_func_sub = proc do |a, b|
  a - b
end

funcs = {
  '+' => my_func_add,
  '-' => my_func_sub
}.freeze

p funcs['+'].call(10, 1)  # => 11
p funcs['-'].call(10, 1)  # => 9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func myFuncAdd(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}

func myFuncSub(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    return a - b
}

let funcs: [String: (Int, Int) -> Int] = [
  "+": myFuncAdd,
  "-": myFuncSub
]

println(funcs["+"]!(10, 1))
println(funcs["-"]!(10, 1))
```

`funcs`がimmutableであることも再現しています。

追記: 削除された重複回答を見て気づいたのですが、Swiftはキャメルケース推奨のようなのでそちらに合わせます。

`ViewController` 内に書く場合のサンプル:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  class func myFuncAdd(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
  }

  class func myFuncSub(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    return a - b
  }

  let funcs: [String: (Int, Int) -> Int] = [
    "+": ViewController.myFuncAdd,
    "-": ViewController.myFuncSub
  ]

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    println(funcs["+"]!(10, 1))
    println(funcs["-"]!(10, 1))
  }
}
```

Comment: 回答にあったコードを ViewController.swift 中に書くとエラーがでます。  

Calculator/ViewController.swift:40:46: '(Int, Int)' is not a subtype of 'ViewController'  

[エラーのスクリーンショット](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/katoy/swift-calculator/master/error.png)  

実は このエラーを解消できずに困っていたので質問をしたのでした。  
　  
試しに swift をコマンドラインで起動して、回答のコードをいれると動作することは確認できました。

Comment: ViewController内に書く場合のサンプルコードを追加しました。

Comment: ViewController 内に書く場合が動作することを確認しました。